# Bootstrap 4 badge not working - just not showing up

Tags: bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm trying to use bootstrap 4 badge in this way:

```
<td><span class="badge badge-warning">{{ object.get_type_display }}</span></td>
```

I'm using:

https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/css/bootstrap.min.css

What can be a reason?

Comment: the reason is there is no badge class in that css.

Comment: There is no badge class in this css.

Comment: @xhulio that's right! Please add this as answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no badge class on that css. Try another version (as far as i've seen there is on alpha.6 version). use the following link:
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css

Answer (score 19):

At least in Bootstrap version **5.1.x** the badges work again after they were dropped in v4.

You can use the following code to display a badge *next to a heading*:

```
<h1>Example heading <span class="badge bg-secondary">New</span></h1>
```

Buttons, background colors and pill badges are now supported as well. You can find the documentation here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/badge/

Comment: That worked for me. Changed mine to bg-primary. Thanks

Answer (score 12):

[`.badge` was dropped in the v4](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/#labels-badges-and-tags):

> Dropped the `.badge` component as it was nearly identical to labels/tags. Use the `.tag-pill` modifier together with the label component instead for that rounded look.

[But they returned it](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/badge/) ([git issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/21565)) so use the **latest** version - [v4.0.0-alpha.6](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css)

Answer (score 11):

There is a tricky way of mixing up `badge` with `alert` classes.

**Example:**

```
<span class="badge alert-success">Active</span>
```

Answer (score 9):

you can't use "badge badge-warning". As per new Documentation in Bootstrap now it is like **"badge bg-warning"**

Check this out:-
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/badge/

Comment: but the question's title and tags specifically mention bootstrap 4, and [v4 badges do have `badge-warning`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/badge/#contextual-variations)

Comment: Thank you! This was driving me nuts I did look at the docs but apparently the wrong version. Relevant answer since I stumbled on this post and it fixed my issue.

Answer (score 7):

It did not work because there was no background colour applied to the badges. Since bootstrap already has a 'bg' component for background colour, I replaced 'badge-warning' with 'bg-warning' and it worked. here is the final look:

```
<span class="badge bg-warning">Primary</span>
```

Answer (score 4):

Incorrect:

```
<span class="badge badge-default badge-pill">1</span>
```

Correct:

```
<span class="badge badge-secondary badge-pill">1</span>
```

Comment: Please edit your post and add some explanation. Why `badge-secondary` is the correct one if OP needs a `badge-warning`? Why is `badge-default` incorrect? (Though I don't see anyone else talking about `badge-default` in this thread.)

Answer (score 4):

Changing `badge-warning` to `bg-warning` worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

In part `class="badge badge-warning"` you can write `class=badge alert-warning` instead of badge keyword in the second part, it helped me with my code.

Answer (score 2):

try this dear

replace "badge" with "bg"

```
 <a href="#" class="badge bg-primary">Primary</a>
<a href="#" class="badge bg-secondary">Secondary</a>
<a href="#" class="badge bg-success">Success</a>
<a href="#" class="badge bg-danger">Danger</a>
<a href="#" class="badge bg-warning">Warning</a>
<a href="#" class="badge bg-info">Info</a>
<a href="#" class="badge bg-light">Light</a>
<a href="#" class="badge bg-dark">Dark</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Walp, I see this is a tad old, but as of now, badge IS supported (contrary to what may have been the case when someone here said otherwise) by bootstrap 4 AND 5... but in bootstrap five, instead of badge-secondary (or info or primary or what-have-you), it's bg-secondary (or info or primary or you-have-what.)

That's ALSO a (modern) reason why the badge background may not show.

Comment: `badge bg-secondary` is working for me in Bootstrap 4.6.0

Answer (score 0):

Is your browser caching disable while debugging?
That could be the reason.

I suggest you use the developers tools to see if your html output gets rendered as expected also.

Answer (score 0):

It was while ago so it requires an update as I've found alpha 6 doesn't contain all the badges (i.e. badge-light).

Today it is better to use latest final release. Use this cdn links for final realease https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/